# Use /proc to display information about the CPU and RAM

Tags: linux

I want to display CPU and RAM information on Linux using /proc. Is it possible to combine these two commands `$ cat /proc/cpuinfo` and `$ cat /proc/meminfo`? Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by *combine*? Why not `cat /proc/cpuinfo /proc/meminfo`? (Note that neither is particularly reliable with cgroups/containers.)

Comment: That's what I was looking for. Thank you:) What do you mean by not reliable with cgroups/containers mean? (I understand cgroups in some way..)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use this:

```
cat /proc/cpuinfo /proc/meminfo
```

Note that the values reported there might be misleading in the presence of containers and cgroups.  Some container frameworks assign fewer resources than what is shown in these pseudo-files to a container.  For example, if you see 1.5 GiB of memory available in `/proc/meminfo`, that does not necessarily mean that your application can allocate even 1 GiB.  Similarly, even if eight cores are listed in `/proc/cpuinfo`, applications in the container might only be scheduled on two cores, for example, even if the application changes CPU affinity.  Some container frameworks simply do not adjust the host information before presenting in to the container through those `/proc` pseudo-files.

Here's how the OpenJDK developers are dealing with this issue:

- [Container aware Java](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8182070)

Comment: OK, I understand. Thank you so much for explaining to me.